# Break up GIT branches into separate directories

Tags: git

I've inherited a Git repo that has one directory and about 20 branches in it.  Each branch contains totally unique code - something with it's own make and source that would normally (if I set it up) be in separate subdirs.  It's very tough for me to work with as is.

How can I break up these 20+ branches into 20 directories, keeping the histories intact of each branch and establish a more traditional Git layout.

Answer (score 1):

You should:

- create a temp folder
- create folders for each branch in your temp folder
- copy all contents of each branch in each folder
- remove the contents in your branch master of your git repository if I understand what you want
- move all contents of temp folder in your git repository

you can automate the process with a shell code thanks to git branch -a

Comment: Thanks. I assume that each new directory will have the branch from the old repo after the cp operation.  Do I just checkout a new branch, say MASTER, from each directory, and merge it in from the old branch, and go from there?

Comment: @user2945953 if you want to restart on clean base I suggest you to delete the others branch